# Why does the Bible change the spelling of fear Exodus 20:20

Tags: hebrew, exodus

The reason for my question is not to find out which is a verb and which is a noun. It’s to find out if the placement of letters, is as claimed purely coincidental or in fact deliberate.

The question mostly stems from the fact that paleo Hebrew did not have the Masorite niqqud, which to me makes sense to add the niqqud in a heavily European environment, centuries later. But (as far as I can tell) the ancient Hebrews, Moses for instance, constructed words differently at least for a different reason than phonetics and pronunciation. And the paleo (non niqqud) lasted even to the time of the prophets where even the prophets constructed new words. Maybe there is something they knew that explains their word formulations.

I’m an advocate of the eth which is largely seen as a direct object pointer, despite it not following this rule all the time and where a direct object pointer would be needed it’s not always added, I’m of the view that it’s to do with Jesus (Apostle John’s Logos or the Word as the ancient Hebrews also called it).

So I was curious if the eth played a role in it been a noun form, and from what I can tell, it is always associated with God or if it is in the verb form the eth follows the verb always (as best as I’ve been able to tell) when in relation to God.

Consider the examples below. This has been consistent in all the texts that I have read so far. When the eth is used for fear it’s always in conjunction with God be it in the word as a noun or after the word when it’s a verb and the eth is not part of the word but it’s about God’s fear.

> Abraham said, “I did it because I thought, ‘There is no fear **(יראת )** of God at all in this place, and they will kill me because of my wife. Genesis 20:11

And

> “so that all the peoples of the earth may know that the hand of the Lord is mighty, that you may fear **( יראתם את)** the Lord your God forever."”
>   ‭‭Joshua‬ ‭4:24‬ ‭

And

> “that you may fear **(תירא את)** the Lord your God, you and your son and your son's son, by keeping all his statutes and his commandments, which I command you, all the days of your life, and that your days may be long.”
>   ‭‭Deuteronomy‬ ‭6:2‬ ‭

I’m imagining that most will assume the language came first and then the writing but supposing the writing influenced the phonetics given it’s paleo hieroglyphs beginning maybe the placement of the letters played a role. Especially in relation to the eth.

Like I said it appears that when the eth is in the word fear, it’s only in relation to God but even when it’s not, because of the verb form the eth follows the verb as if to confirm it’s specially ‘a fear of God’.

Hence my original question, is there anything special about the eth? Apparently not and all I’d need would be a deviation from this coincidental observation of the text. Thank you

———————————————

If you read in the Hebrew the word for fear changes spelling in the same verse

> “And Moses said unto the people, Fear (תיראו ) not: for God is come to prove you, and that his fear (יראתו) may be before your faces, that ye sin not.”
>   ‭‭Exodus‬ ‭20:20‬

Why not use the same word?

Comment: These alternate spellings are not limited to this verse. Sometimes it’s spelt one way and others the other way

Comment: They're not "moving"; they're different affixes whose forms are coincidentally similar. The words aren't even the same word class!

Comment: @curiousdannii fair enough, maybe you can explain why the two word classes?

Comment: What's to explain? We need both nouns and verbs.

Comment: I’ll take responsibility for the question but I’m not essentially wanting to know what I can research for myself, I was more interested in why these two letters were used exactly and not different letters for example. If they were significant especially in light of the eth (as an object pointer). Personally I don’t believe it was purely a phonetic decision. Maybe the paleo Hebrew might shed some light, maybe not. But regardless I get the impression this is the wrong place to ask though I imagined it was hermeneutics related. I kept the question broad but maybe I shouldn’t have @curiousdannii

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first word, תיראו (*thiyrau*), is the second person plural form of the **verb** "to fear" (i.e., "fear [ye]"), whereas the second word יראתו (*yirathu*) is the **noun** "fear" (the suffix ו, *wa*, denoting the masculine possessive, indicating that it is "his"). These are not spelling differences, but differences in form depending on and denoting the grammatical function of a word in a given sentence.

Comment: I’m not so much interested in what they communicate but how they were constructed as words. It doesn’t seem that they were necessarily constructed purely on phonetic basis. I was hoping for something more than what I know and can find out for myself through basic research. I’m not so sure this community would be open to exploring the possibility of word origin from the paleo Hebrew. Thank you for taking the time to respond but not really what I was wanting to find out.  I tried to keep the question broad enough not to taint the direction of the question but definitely not what I was expecting.

Comment: "the second person plural form" is missing the name of the conjugation and the gender. The suffix is *ō*, not *wa*.

Comment: I felt it sufficient to point out a difference in word kind, rather than other more pedantic distinctions; I meant the letter *waw *is suffixed, not the sound it represents.

Comment: I thinks this was an excellent answer +1.

Comment: @Autodidact You've changed your question beyond recognition (about 95% of it); I answered the one you asked. The one you're now asking is entirely different.

Comment: But it is phonology rather than spelling that makes out how the word should be parsed. You can still edit your answer, anyway; also one "differences" can be removed.

Comment: I think the transliteration will suffice for now; I don't want to complicate a simple answer to a simple question.